# SharePoint : Issue creating Disco

Tags: sharepoint, discovery, disco

I've followed the instructions [here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx) to the letter, when I run disco.exe I get this error:

The HTML document does not contain web service discovery information.

Any suggestions?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems with the declaration:

```
<% @ WebService Language="C#" Class="MOSS_WebServices.My_Services, MOSS_WebServices ,  

Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b40cb3309a7591b" %>
```

Answer (score -2):

When you run Disco.exe against your asmx file you may experience very 
inconvenient message "HTML document does not contain Web service 
discovery information". In my case it was very important to see the exact error message. Please find answer at http://malcan.com/EN/Lists/Tips%20and%20tricks/DispForm.aspx?ID=25

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation with that website and should post the answer here instead of just linking to it.

Comment: agree with @John Conde.